# Why does placing resistors in parallel decrease the resistance?

Tags: current, resistors

This question has been asked before but I don't understand the answers to it. They say that by adding a resistor, it provides an additional path for current to flow  and decreases the resistance. I understand how an additional path decreases resistance but how is adding another resistor  adding an additional path? For example, say a parallel circuit branches off into two paths. You then add resistors to those two paths. How does that decrease the resistance? It isn't adding a new path?

Comment: If you add a resistor in parallel, the current goes up.  For the current to increase, the resistance must of decreased.

Comment: Why does the current go up if resistors slow down the flow of electrons? I understand that resistance decreases as current increases but I don't get the first part.

Comment: why can you get more cars down the road if you add more lanes?

Comment: You have added a second path for electrons.

Comment: Oh okay sorry I misunderstood what you meant by adding a resistor in parallel. Thanks.

Comment: Add a second hole in your bucket and you have a bigger leak, less resistance

Comment: RE "Why does the current go up if resistors slow down the flow of electrons?": Every resistor is also a conductor.

Comment: So you have this huge pressure compared to the path the electrons can flow in. Adding more paths allows some of the pressure to drop but the pressure is so big compared to the path the electrons can flow through that this drop is negligible and all you measure is the increased flow? So even though there is resistance, the fact that there are more paths for this huge pressure is way stronger than the increased resistance?

Answer (score 5):

There's a waterfall pushing 600 gallons per second. You divert a small section through a small water hose giving you 5 gallons per second. Your current is 5 gallons per second.

Add another of the same size hose. You more have 2 currents that add up to 10 gallons per second.

It's like a single hose that does 10 gallons per second.

This is an approximation of how parallel resistors work.

Answer (score 2):

The second resistor *is* a second path for the current. Consider the following circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZDhS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first circuit, with V1, is your initial circuit. It's one volt across a one ohm resistor, with one amp of current. Next, you add a second one ohm resistor, as in the circuit with V2. Both resistors have one volt across them, so both resistors have one amp through them. That's just ohm's law. Since there are two resistors, that's a total of two amps coming from the source. The circuit connected to V3 shows an identical circuit from the source's point of view: one volt over half an ohm is two amps, just like with the two parallel resistors.

Answer (score 1):

A parallel circuit decreases the resistance compared to a circuit where there are no parallel branches. Say you had 2 100 ohm resistors in parallel. Then you add a third 100 ohm resistor in parallel with the first two. Now the current has three path to go through compared to two, so it increases.

In the example you provided of adding resistors to a parallel circuit with no resistors initially, that would decrease current.

Adding parallel resistors only increases current if there was not initially a parallel branch at all.